# Aggregating Amounts from Different Tables

Tags: sql, hive, union, hiveql, full-outer-join

I have a table `t1` like this:

```
store_id    industry_id    cust_id    amount     gender     age
1           100            1000       1.00       M          20
2           100            1000       2.05       M          20
3           100            1000       3.15       M          20
4           200            2000       5.00       F          30
5           200            2000       6.00       F          30
```

And another table `t2` that looks like this:

```
store_id    industry_id    cust_id    amount   
10          100            1000       10.00   
20          200            2000       11.00
```

Suppose we want to construct a table with all of the transactions for a given customer in each industry. In other words, something like this:

```
store_id.   industry_id.   cust_id.   amount
1           100            1000       1.00
2           100            1000       2.05
3           100            1000       3.15
4           200            2000       5.00
5           200            2000       6.00
10          100            1000       10.00
20          200            2000       11.00
```

I'm trying to do this by using a join and a coalesce statement in the query below, but it doesn't work because each row has an entry for the `amount` column in `t1`, i.e., there aren't any NULL values for the coalesce statement to use. What's the best way to do this using a join?

```
SELECT
a.store_id,
a.industry_id,
a.cust_id,
COALESCE(a.amount,b.amount,0) AS amount
FROM t1 a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT store_id AS store_id_2, industry_id AS industry_id_2, cust_id AS cust_id_2, amount FROM t2) b 
ON a.cust_id=b.cust_id_2 AND a.industry_id=b.industry_id_2;
```

This query results in:

```
store_id    industry_id    cust_id    amount     
1           100            1000       1.00  
2           100            1000       2.05  
3           100            1000       3.15  
4           200            2000       5.00 
5           200            2000       6.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this dataset `union all` seems good enough:

```
select store_id, industry_id, cust_id, amount from t1
union all
select store_id, industry_id, cust_id, amount from t2
```

I am speculating that the same store / industry / customer tuple may appear in both tables and you want just one row in the result with the sum the corresponding amounts. If so, you might be interested in a `full join`:

```
select
    coalesce(t1.store_id, t2.store_id) store_id,
    coalesce(t1.industry_id, t2.industry_id) industry_id,
    coalesce(t1.cust_id, t2.cust_id) cust_id,
    coalesce(t1.amount, 0) + coalesce(t2.amount, 0) amount
from t1
full join t2 
    on t2.store = t1.store and t2.industry = t1.industry and t2.cust_id = t1.cust_id
```

Comment: Thank you. This is indeed a snippet of a larger query. Is this possible to achieve with a left join?

Comment: @Caerus: for your sample data, a `left join` is not appropriate. You have rows in both tables that do not belong to the other one.